# Why is Jenkins not using the correct image for docker builds?

Tags: docker, jenkins

No matter what I try, I seem to be unable toget a declerative pipeline to build my project inside a docker container, with the correct image.

I have verified the following:

- Jenkins does build the correct image (based on messages in the log)
- When I build the image manually, it is build correctly
- When building the project inside a container with the correct image, the build succeeds
- The Jenkins steps do run in a container with *some* image.

As far as I can tell, Jenkins simply uses the base image and not the correct one, resulting from the dockerfile I specify.

Things I've tried:

Let Jenkins figure it out

```
pipeline {
    agent dockerfile
```

Using docker at the top level:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile { 
            filename 'Dockerfile'
            reuseNode true
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('configure') {
            steps {
```

Use docker in each step

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('configure') {
            agent {
                dockerfile { 
                    filename 'Dockerfile'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            steps {
```

Abbreviations, due to the number of examples. Docker is not mentioned anywhere outside of the specified areas and simply removing the docker parts and using a regular agent works fine.

## Logs

The logs are useless. They simply state that they build the image and verify that they exist and then fail to execute commands that have just been installed (meson in this case).

Comment: `build my project inside a docker container`. Do you mean that you run jenkins in a docker container?

Comment: If you are using a Jenkins plugin to build docker images, which plugin(s) are you using?

Comment: @justthink No. I mean building my project inside a docker container. It's a standard feature of Jenkins to do this. No plugins required, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest you to read:

- [The Pipeline syntax for the `agent` declaration](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) and in particular the `dockerfile` section
- [This basic example on how to use `dockerfile`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#dockerfile). Start with the minimal pipeline with `agent { dockerfile true }` and please show us the logs for example.

Without any logs or a more detailed explanation on your setup, it is difficult to help you.
I can certainly tell you that the second try is wrong because

> `reuseNode` is valid for `docker` and `dockerfile`, and only has an effect when used on an `agent` for an individual `stage`.

Instead, I am not sure how the third try could ever work: with `agent none` you are forcing each stage to have an `agent` section, but in the stage's `agent` section you have the `reuseNode` option set to true. Isn't it a contradiction? How could you reuse a top-level node if this one does not exist?

I know it is not an answer, but it is also too long to stay in the comments in my opinion.

Comment: Naturally, I already read the articles you linked to :-) Otherwise I would never have made any of my attempts. The last two attempts were really in desperation and not something I would expect to work (which they also didn't). They were included because I did make the attempts.

Comment: I suggested you those 2 links after seeing the tries you have done, but I imagined they were out of despair :) Well, if you have tried the minimal breaking pipeline and there aren't any useful logs, I do not think we can easily help you, unless you find someone who experienced your same error. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example or is that too much complex?

Answer (score 1):

I always use it like this, with a pre-build image:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker { image 'node:16-alpine' }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
         sh 'node --version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I can only guess what you want to do inside the docker environment.

Comment: Using a pre-build image is not an option, sadly.